# Normalizing historical data in time-series LSTMs

Tags: neural-network, time-series, lstm, normalization, batch-normalization

I am currently trying to solve a sequence prediction problem using LSTMs in a keras architecture. To illustrate the problem I give the following example which resemble the problem I must solve.

Lets assume I am using climate data to model a very specific temperature phenomenon that only happens in a given week during the spring. I am using the past few days as well as historical data to predict the temperature each day for the next week. My network takes two inputs and one output.

- Input 1 is the **daily** mean temperature & precipitation for the past 5 days (sequence length=5).
- Input 2 are the **weekly** mean temperature & precipitation from the past 6 months (sequence length=24).
- Output is the temperature tomorrow.

Furthermore, lets assume that my data comes from several cities around the world with very different climates such that normalizing the data across batches is very troublesome.

Let the batch size be 7 such that each batch predicts the temperature for the next 7 days for the given city.

I know that to get a model with robust prediction power I should use the changes over time instead of the values (e.g. "time n" to "time n+1" to predict the change from "time n+1" to "time n+2") but that leaves me with the following issues:

- *How should I normalize the data given that the values from Input 2 are likely to be VERY different from those in Input 1 for each batch (since they cover different seasons)?*

I think a batch normalization layer right after each input layer would work. However, I am not sure if that would mean that the network would "disassociate" the two inputs so-to-speak. Using batch normalization, I fear that the model would no longer recognize that the sequence in Input 2 leads up to the sequence in Input 1.

- *Is this a real consequence of batch normalization or does the NN handle it automatically?*
- *Can a control variable, like a constant that represents the difference between the means of each input, solve this?*

Remember that the scenario is fake, it is simply meant as an illustration of this approach. To be clear the question is:

**Is batch normalization after each input layer (and maybe subsequent layers) safe or should I normalize each batch before the input and not use batch normalization layers?**